# How to redirect the new website without changing the existing url

Tags: c#, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to open a new website within my website without changing the existing URL.

Suppose I have a website siteA and it have one page main.html, my question is that how I show siteB (new site) when I open the siteA/main.htm but my url still same, no change in url but site is different.

I open siteB when I want otherwise siteA still browsing.

I want to do this without changing. htaccess file. I want to do this using any programming language like C#, PHP Dynamically.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I guess you could use an iframe... This seems shady though and I wouldn't want that behavior as a user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this! Usually sites will do this for phishing purposes to obfuscate the site the user is on in order to collect personal information.

If you were to have this on a website, it would likely be flagged as fraudulent by the browser. I'd consider a different architectural approach to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes exactly i want to do this. i want  to play with google adword so web croawler not see what i want to display the user. i just want to play with the technology. So please tell me how i do this if you really know who to do this..

Comment: Not really sure without understanding more about what your trying to solve. I'd recommend posting another question or updating this one. My guess is others are running into similar issues that you currently have.